# Currency NumberFormat change the `format` behaviour after calling `parse`

Tags: android, kotlin, number-formatting

I create a numberFormat to not return strings with decimals like:

```
val numberFormat = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().apply {
    minimumFractionDigits = 0
}
```

1. If I call format it returns fine

```
numberFormat.format(123) // "$123"
```

2. If I call parse with other value

```
numberFormat.parse("$333") // a number -> 333
```

3. And call format again with 123, the returned value contains the decimals! **the format changed!**.

```
numberFormat.format(123) // "$123.00"
```

Why? What can we do so it returns always with `format` without decimals like **1.**?

I made a repo to reproduce it: https://github.com/danielgomezrico/test-numericformat-format-parse-error-sample.

It looks like it only fails on android not in java.

Take a look to [MainActivity.kt](https://github.com/danielgomezrico/test-numericformat-format-parse-error-sample/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/test/MainActivity.kt)

Comment: Cannot reproduce: https://paiza.io/projects/-l27aKglwqYH3LxRZu_n2Q?language=kotlin

Comment: @Marvin I copied the exact text from this answer into an empty android project and was able to reproduce it no problem

Comment: @Marvin wonder if the bug is somehow tied to android...

Comment: @Quinn: Probably then. I don't have an android project to verify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never used `NumberFormat` so I am not sure why it acts like that... but one work around would be to make your `numberFormat` a class variable with a custom getter like so:

```
val numberFormat: NumberFormat
    get() = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().apply { maximumFractionDigits = 0 }
```

and then when you access it this way, it will apply the `maximumFractionDigits` each time

Comment: Thanks, I got the same results with that for some reason :(

Comment: @DanielGomezRico odd, it works for me [code snipped from my onCreate method](https://imgur.com/a/5ZZreu4)

Comment: I made a repo to reproduce it https://github.com/danielgomezrico/test-numericformat-format-parse-error-sample

Comment: @DanielGomezRico your GitHub repo doesn't implement it how I explain in my answer